# Linux: Remove files from destination which has been removed from source

Tags: linux

I Would like to reach the following:

> 1. create destination folder, if it does not exist.
> 2. copy the files, which has been changed from source foo/src to destination foo/dest
> 3. if some files has been been removed from src, then remove them also from destination.

I tried the following:

```
1. mkdir -p foo/dest
2. yes | cp -a -u foo/src/* foo/dest
3. how to do step 3?
```

I am not sure about step 2 and I dont know to reach point 3. I hope somebody can help.

Comment: check out this post. http://superuser.com/a/410290/540740

Comment: Take a look at `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync --delete` instead of `cp` to do step 2 and step 3 at the same time.